# How to update material dropdown in R to have value and choices set to NULL

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I would like to clear the choices in my material dropdown when an event is triggered.

```
observeEvent(input$rfpsList, {
    update_material_dropdown(session, "projectList", choices = NULL, value = NULL)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately I am getting a error message: `ERROR: Must include 'value' with update_material_dropdown`.

I have tried the following:

setting value = character(0). It did not do much, since the choices were still there.

Changing to `selectInput` and `updateSelectInput`. However none of the choices are visible then. I think it doesnt work well while ushing shinymaterial.

Any other ideas?

Comment: what about setting it to an empty string? `value = c('')`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work too

Comment: What is the interest of the dropdown if it has no choice? Why don't you hide it instead?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, I thought about it too, but I have no luck with conditionalPanel. The same issue occures.